# Crystal reports -The document has not been opened

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a few Crystal Reports on my website. In my local machine it is working, but in the test environment, in another server when trying to use the report I get the following problem:

[image]

I can't imagine what can be the problem, because I'm using the same DDL's and configs on the test environment, too.

I even tried with the Process monitor, and I don't see any errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFvmn.png)

Comment: Check the path. Can you get the "filename" parameter?

Comment: I have updated the question. I don't know how to check if I get the "filename" parameter. In my local machine it is working ok. With the Process monitor installed on that server where I get the problem, it seems that the Process monitor return Success

Answer (score 5):

this is crystal report version problem. remove old version. reinstall new version.
for vs 2013 use CRforVS_13_0_23.

Comment: This was the answer.  I realized I had an old version of the runtime installed on my machine, but was using a newer version of the package in the .NET app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *IIS*:

- Go to the application pool
- Select your web site
- Click on Advanced Settings on the right side
- Set 'Enable 32-bit application' true

Crystal report runtime engine for .net 32-bit had to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

My problem sorted with the following crystal version.
CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_20

First, uninstall any other crystal runtime version and install this again.

Answer (score 0):

After installing CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_21.msi I started seeing this error using the Crystal Viewer within an ASP.NET web application. These reports previously worked using a prior version of the crystal runtime **so the quick fix is to uninstall 13.0.21 runtime and install CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_20.msi (or lower) in its place and reports will most likely work.**

This is known** Crystal Reports issue when web applications are published to an environment that is running the Crystal runtime 13.0.21 or higher while your application's binaries were built using the earlier 13.0.20 or earlier runtime in your build environment. With the release of 13.0.21 and later you now need to have them both at the same level, either both at .20 or lower, or both at .21 of higher.

** "As most of CR/RAS .NET Assemblies are now re-versioned from 13.0.2000.0 to 13.0.3500.0 and for SP 26 are now 13.0.4000.0, user MUST remove all old CR assemblies from Reference list and add the new version of CR assemblies, then rebuild the application." ref. https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports,+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

There may be one way around this, by using a special runtime section in the web.config but I haven't tested whether that will help this specific issue so I won't include it here.